# How to set GET variable in web browser?

Tags: php, mysql

`query('SELECT name FROM flags WHERE id='.$_GET['id']);`

- 127.0.0.1/?id=1
- 127.0.0.1/?id='.1

These not working. How can I do this correctly?

Comment: Not working means have you got any error or something???

Comment: @Saty no, this is security exercise but I don't have idea how to solve this. We need to put id GET variable correctly, as in sql query.

Answer (score 2):

use  `mysql_reaL_escape_string`

```
$id = mysql_reaL_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM flags WHERE id='$id'");
```

> mysql_real_escape_string — Escapes special characters in a string for
>   use in an SQL statement

Answer (score -1):

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
$sql=mysql query("SELECT name FROM flags WHERE id='$id'";
```

and link Is ex:127.0.0.1/xxx.php?id=1
try this

Comment: I can't change SQL query :)

Comment: i never change sql query. just modified and do simply.